# Creating automatic labels in form to display value from database

Tags: c#

Was trying out a simple FB API app to retrieve status.
So what i am intending to do is to perform a word check with my dictionary.
I have a database which stores emotive data on the feeling % and the genre of the feeling.
If the status contains the emotive word, i wish to perform a word analysis.
For instance: "I am feeling sad and angry"

So what i want it to display is like...
"Username"
       was feeling
               50% angry
                  and 25% sad.

*% is calculated by random function.
However, i think its impossible for me to keep creating labels. What if my status has > 5 emotions? Is it possible to create automatic labels which would display the output?

Below is my code:

```
 private void EmotionAnalysis_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = tpc.loadInfo(currentId)["target_name"].ToString();
            //List<DataRow> result = dict.AngerPercent(fbStatus);
            CalculateAndDisplayAnalysis("Angry", topPercentLabel, topFeelingLabel);
            CalculateAndDisplayAnalysis("Caring", bottomPercentLabel, bottomFeelingLabel);

            //var item = new ListViewItem(new[] { "", String.Format("{0}%", percent.ToString()), result[0]["Genre"].ToString() });
            //listViewEmotion.Items.Add(item);
        }

        private void CalculateAndDisplayAnalysis(string genre, Label percentLabel, Label feelingLabel)
        {
            List<DataRow> result = dict.GenrePercent(fbStatus, genre);
            var rnd = new Random();
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                total += rnd.Next(Convert.ToInt32(result[i]["Min_Percentage"]), Convert.ToInt32(result[i]["Max_Percentage"]));
            }
            if (result.Count != 0)
            {
                int percent = total / result.Count;
                percentLabel.Text = String.Format("{0}%", percent.ToString());
                feelingLabel.Text = result[0]["Genre"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many labels as you want. you just need to set the position of the label and add it to the forms Controls enumeration:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "MyText";
lbl.Location = new Position(xPos, yPos);
this.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

You will have to keep track of the new position which is in this case determined by `xPos` and `yPos`